# Qt:signal slot pass by const reference

Tags: c++, qt, pass-by-reference, signals-slots, pass-by-value

Many qt examples did the following things:

```
signal: passByConstRef(const QImage &)
slot: receivedByConstRef( const QImage &)
```

They are connected through queued connection in different threads.
In thread 1:

```
{QImage image; 
 image = fromData(...);
 emit passByConstRef(image);
}
```

In thread 2:

```
receivedByConstRef(const QImage& image){
   ...
   pixmap = fromImage(image);
   ...
 }
```

Since the signal slot is passing the QImage by const Ref which means there's no copy happening, will it be possible that when "pixmap" is being constructed, the life time of "image" in thread 1 is over and leads to the failure of constructing "pixmap" in thread 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass an argument by reference, a copy would be sent in a queued connection. Indeed the arguments are always copied when you have a queued connection. So here there would be no trouble regarding the life time of images since it will be copied instead of passed by reference.

Comment: So it is changed to pass by value inside qt? And there is no need to add any mutex for the "image" right?

Comment: Yeah it would be copied. There is no need for a mutex.

Comment: While a copy is indeed sent, the explaination provided here is wrong. 1) Queued connections always copy the arguments. It does not matter if they're passed by value or by (const) reference. 2) The normalized signature has nothing to do with this.

Comment: But. Someone told me that the passed object must be registered with qt's metaobject system to make sure that a copy will be made.

Comment: @Nyaruko Yes a type should be registered to be used in a queued connection. But i think `QImage` is  supported by `QMetaType` by default.

Comment: @Nejat you're right. `QImage` is supported by `QMetaType`, also it has COW implementation, so there will be no overhead on copying objects. Cross-thread syncronization will be done automatially by Qt event system.

Comment: Then, how about the qbytearray?

Comment: QByteArray is also supported. See the list of types that are supported by default : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html